# n-dimensional simplex

Tags: geometry, simplex

I am working with compositional data which has simplex geometry. For example, If I have concentrations of 4 chemical elements closed to 100% then they correspond to tetrahedral, where every element is a component. 
My question is next. If I have an infinite number of components in my simplex, would it be then a sphere? How could one prove that?

Comment: No.  It would be a very high dimensional analog of a tetrahedron.

Comment: Thanks for a reply! I do not understand why though but I believe that you are probably right.

Comment: One difference between tetrahedra and spheres (or rather, balls) is that the former have flat sides and the latter do not: every point in the boundary of a ball is an extreme point, but not so for tetrahedra.  Another is that each point in a tetrahedron can be represented as a convex combo of extreme points in exactly one way, but not so for balls.  Going to infinite dimensions does not change these.